# Iterate the keys and values from the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I access the dictionary's key and value and iterate over for loop?

```
dictionary = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"}
```

My output will be like:

```
1  one
2  two
3  three
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this code snippet.

```
dictionary = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c"}

# To iterate over the keys
for key in dictionary.keys():  # or `for key in dictionary`
    print(key)

# To iterate over the values
for value in dictionary.values():
    print(value)

# To iterate both the keys and values
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print(key, '\t', value)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> Return a new view of the dictionary’s items (`(key, value)` pairs)

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this to get the desired output:

```py
dictionary = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"}

for i in dictionary.keys():
    print(i, dictionary[i])
```

Output:

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
```